# Cat/grep just the lines with single ip

Tags: grep, cat

I have a file something like this

```
Script http://127.0.0.1/ blabla
127.0.0.1
Script 127.0.0.2/index.html bla bla
127.0.0.2
Script 127.0.0.3/contact bla bla
Script 127.0.0.4/settings bla bla
127.0.0.4
```

I want to get only the lines that contain just a single ip not all the ips from all the lines.

How can i do this?

the results should be

```
127.0.0.1
127.0.0.2
127.0.0.4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `cat` utility just concatenates the data given to it, so it would not be of much use here.

Assuming it's ok to be somewhat sloppy with what constitutes a *valid* IP address:

```
grep -Ex '([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}' file
```

This would match and print any lines matching the given regular expression (and discard the others).

An even sloppier solution would be to discard lines that contains anything but dots and digits:

```
grep -v '[^0-9.]' file
```

Depending on your requirements, one of these would be enough.

For a completely correct regular expression (does not match invalid IP addresses), you could use

```
grep -Ex '((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9]?[0-9])\.){3}(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9]?[0-9])' file
```

Comment: none of those work...

Comment: cat putty.txt | grep -v '[^0-9.]'
Binary file (standard input) matches

Comment: root@localhost:~# grep -Ex '([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}' putty.txt
root@localhost:~#

Comment: @Killroy2018 I've tested all of these on the data you provided, and they all work.  If `grep` is saying that the file is "binary", then you are not working with a text file, and certainly not the file that you posted.

Comment: sorry mate, you are right, if i test it with my example or similar it works fine. I have to see the particularities of my specific file as i cand give a real sample. It is the saved output from putty, it is text

Comment: It must be from the putty save output that i then upload to the server as txt file. If i copy from the file on my pc and paste it using nano on the server...it works...that’s odd. Explains why i was struggling with this issue